# Angularjs: Iterator array from end with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want show a list of an array from last element to first element by `ng-repeat` in angularjs.

For this, I try some solutions like:

```
<div ng-repeat="ms in preConv.messages track by ms.sortElement">
```

or

```
<div ng-repeat="ms in preConv.messages | order by ms.sortElement track by ms.sortElement">
```

but didn`t find solution.

I can first sort the array, but I want to know can I do this without sorting array and just preview from end of array by `ng-repeat`?

Comment: `order by` should be `orderBy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to reverse you need to add `-`

```
  <div ng-repeat="ms in preConv.messages | orderBy: '-sortElement'></div>`
```